# Odoo Record Rule enable/disable based on active model

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In odoo I have a model named test.lines and its a one2many into two other objects part.one and part.two..and I have some record rules on object test.lines . Now my question is I want record rule to check test.lines object only when I access it from the from view of part.one

when I open form view of part.two then record rule on model test.lines should not be trigger

Note : test.lines is one2many in both part.one and part.two

i do not know how to do it

Comment: IMO that's not a requirement you should solve by access rules, because they are based on one model, a domain and groups (accept for global rules). There is no single relation to other models (in the domain yes, but not in the rule itself) and/or views.

Comment: it not very clear your question. Your security record rules are with what purpose?

Comment: my purpose is to enable/disable record rule of one2many based on parent model, test.lines is o2m in 2 separate objects A and B and both form view are different so I want to add record rule on test.lines when I access test.lines from A form view then record rule should work..and disable it when i access test.lines via from view of B